# xDebug issue after upgrade php5.5.x to php5.6

Tags: php, sublimetext3, sublimetext, xdebug, php-5.6

I am having an issue with **xdebug** + **sublime text 3** after upgrade php 5.5.x to 5.6.0

**The error:**

```
Please restart Xdebug debugging session.
Disconnected from Xdebug debugger engine.
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 1023: unexpected end of data
```

Here is my `php -v` output:

```
PHP 5.6.19-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli)  Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.4.1-dev, Copyright (c) 2002-2016, by Derick Rethans
```

There is my **/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini** (only xdebug config):

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension = /usr/lib/php5/20131226/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_mode = req
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
display_errors = On
html_errors = On
```

pd: my **xdebug.sublime-settings - User** is:

```
{
    "max_depth": 5
}
```

This issue is not usual, sometimes works OK

**UPDATE**

I set `true`  to `"debug"` variable in my xdebug client...

```
// Show detailed log information about communication
// between debugger engine and Sublime Text.
// Log can be found at Packages/User/Xdebug.log
"debug": true
```

Checking the Xdebug.log:

```
[03/16/2016 08:24:30PM] DEBUG - [Send command] context_get -i 18
[03/16/2016 08:27:08PM] INFO - Connection lost with debugger engine.
[03/16/2016 08:27:08PM] DEBUG - 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 1023: unexpected end of data
[03/16/2016 08:27:09PM] DEBUG - [Send command] stack_get -i 19
[03/16/2016 08:27:09PM] INFO - Connection lost with debugger engine.
[03/16/2016 08:27:09PM] DEBUG - 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
```

I still have no idea how to fix it...

Comment: Try tu use xdebug var localhost/project/index.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=1

Comment: It doesn't work :/

Comment: I recommend that you create a "remote debugging log", as is described at https://xdebug.org/support.php#remote and attach the initial communication here as an edit to your post. This log would show all communication between Sublime and Xdebug. I am thinking there is an Xdebug bug because of ```[03/16/2016 08:27:09PM] INFO - Connection lost with debugger engine.``` and not because of the "decode" issue, so you might want to follow all the instructions at https://xdebug.org/support.php#remote and file a bug report at http://bugs.xdebug.org

Comment: I installed netbeans working perfectly... Sublime is doing something wrong? There are another xdebug client for sublime?? I am using package 'xdebug client'. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I had same error with xdebug client after changing the max_depth parameters. I had to reset max_depth to 1 to make xdebug work again.